# Why can't ogre_tools find wxWidgets for rviz on OS X?

Tags: rviz, macos, ogre, wxwidgets, macos-lion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to compile rviz on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 but I'm having some problems with ogre_tools and wxWidgets. Apparently ogre_tools is not finding wxWidgets. Here's the output:

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package ogre_tools
[rosbuild] Including /Users/cabrita/ros/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /Users/cabrita/ros/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /Users/cabrita/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.7/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.7/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.7/share/cmake/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:831 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ogre_tools written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/cabrita/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120319-140458/ogre_tools/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< ogre_tools [FAIL] [ 0.71 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ogre_tools.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit [PASS] [ 0.54 seconds ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_srvs [PASS] [ 0.73 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs [PASS] [ 3.94 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 21 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /Users/cabrita/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120319-140458

I have already done rosdep install rviz with the following output: "All required rosdeps installed successfully".

On the tutorial it is said that wxWidgets should be installed by rosdep, "This installer is downloaded and run automatically for you by rosdep..." from http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29964/why-can%27t-ogre_tools-find-wxwidgets-for-rviz-on-os-x?/) by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 591 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-03-20**:
Some developments, I was thinking that maybe rosdep didn't install the wx stuff so I tested the wxPython install with the python shell using: `import wx' and it cannot find the pkg. So I'm guessing wxPython is not install and probably neither is wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved!

Apparently rosdep didn't install wxPython/wxWidgets the first time, however it did create the file that led rosmake to think so.

The solution was to remove the file:

$ cd /usr/local/share/ros/
$ rm wxpython-version.installed

And then rerun rosdep:

$ rosdep install rviz

After which I was able to successfully rosmake rviz!

I found the solution while going through similar questions:

http://answers.ros.org/question/12323/rxtools-fails-under-osx-lion-and-homebrew

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) with karma: 591 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0